# getting warning while installing distribution certificate after device test successfully done

Tags: ios, xcode

I am getting warning when i created appstore method and installed distributted certificate:

> "A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in
>   you keychain".

Any solution for this..remaining all done. struck in this..

In my key chain i have seen like below:

> 1) iPhone developer: my name
>
> MyApp   private key
>
> 2) My company name  certificate
>
> My company name   private key

Comment: Do you have your account  Dist. Cert in your keychain? Private + public keys?

Comment: I have edited my post.pls see Philip

Comment: Need to provide a little more info about the distribution profile, what certificate is it using, and what private key is attached to it.  Also, how did you install this profile on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that your identifier is currect and you have selected right profile.
2. In app dev center make new dist profile, 
   delete the old one from device organizer and install the new one.
3. See that you have your certifications installed in device organizer.